# runaway argument?

Tags: graphics, floats, subfloats

Here is the minimal example. It gives me error
Runaway argument?

> {\includegraphics [width=3in]{readavail13.jpg} \label {Worst Quorum
>   S\ETC. ! File ended while scanning use of \sf@@@subfloat.  
>                   \par

```
\documentclass[final,leqno,onefignum,onetabnum]{siamltex1213}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{subfig}
\title{USING SIAM'S \LaTeX\ MACROS\thanks{This work was
supported by the Society for Industrial and Applied
Mathematics}}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section{example}
\begin{figure}[H]
\subfloat[Read Availability (13 copies)]{\includegraphics[width=3in]{readavail13.jpg}
\label{Worst Quorum Size}
\hfil
\subfloat[Read Availability (40 copies)]{\includegraphics[width=3in]{readavail40.jpg}
\label{Optimal Quorum Size}
\caption{Read Availability}
\label{ra}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

The **siamlatex1213.cls** file can be found at http://www.siam.org/journals/auth-info.php.

Comment: there's a `}` missing after the `{readavail40.jpg}`

Comment: ... and after `{readavail13.jpg}` as well.

Answer (score 2):

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{demo}{graphicx}%% DELETE it
\documentclass[final,leqno,onefignum,onetabnum]{siamltex1213}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{subfig}
\title{USING SIAM'S \LaTeX\ MACROS\thanks{This work was
supported by the Society for Industrial and Applied
Mathematics}}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section{example}
\begin{figure}[!htb]
\subfloat[Read Availability (13 copies)]{\includegraphics[width=3in]{readavail13.jpg}}
\label{Worst Quorum Size}
\hfill
\subfloat[Read Availability (40 copies)]{\includegraphics[width=3in]{readavail40.jpg}}
\label{Optimal Quorum Size}
\caption{Read Availability}
\label{ra}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

But this example runs only if I delete the `dvips` and `pdfmark` option in the class file. It expects by default `latex` -> `dvips` -> `ps2pdf`. And this route doesn't allow a jpg image.

[image]